# How to solve an error with sum calculations?

Tags: r, sum, tidyverse, summarize

I want to take the sum of the columns `aantal_vangtuigeenheden` and `totaalgewicht_vangst` which I used the following code:

```
Data_traject <- Data_trajectgegevens_ruw
Data_traject$datum                  <- as.Date(Data_traject$datum, format="%Y-%m-%d")
#Data_traject$tijd                  <- format(as.POSIXct(strptime(Data_traject$tijd,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="")) ,format = "%H:%M:%S")
Data_traject$jaar                   <- as.character(Data_traject$jaar)
Data_traject$projectnr              <- as.character(Data_traject$projectnr)
Data_traject$waterdiepte_m          <- as.numeric(Data_traject$waterdiepte_m)
Data_traject$`aantal nachten`       <- round(Data_traject$`aantal nachten`, digits = 0)
Data_traject$totaalgewicht_vangst   <- as.numeric(Data_traject$totaalgewicht_vangst)
Data_traject$`datum opgehaald`      <- as.Date(Data_traject$`datum opgehaald`, format="%Y-%m-%d")

library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

cpue_monitoring <- cpue_monitoring %>%
  mutate(Datum = format(date(`datum opgehaald`), "%Y-%m-%d")) %>%
  group_by(locatie, deelgebied, `datum opgehaald`) %>% 
  summarise_at(c("aantal_vangtuigeenheden", "totaalgewicht_vangst"), sum)
```

It seems that most values are calculated correctly, accept for the values that are `36` in the column `aantal_vangtuigeenheden`. They need to be a total of `48`. That means that R scipped some rows while doing the calculations. I checked my excel file and the Rfiles, but everything seems to be fine. How can I find the problem in this situation?

My dataset (Data_trajectgegevens_ruw):

```
structure(list(session_id = c("603f969cfe8bbdd01626160511037", 
"603f969cfe8bbdd01626161288920", "603f969cfe8bbdd01626162683971", 
"603f969cfe8bbdd01626163130030", "603f969cfe8bbdd01626164875835", 
"603f969cfe8bbdd01626165715889", "603f969cfe8bbdd01626166106312", 
"603f969cfe8bbdd01626166256346", "603f969cfe8bbdd01626873692255", 
"603f969cfe8bbdd01626869325405", "603f969cfe8bbdd01626872255866", 
"603f969cfe8bbdd01626872457158", "603f969cfe8bbdd01626871454531", 
"603f969cfe8bbdd01628165008181", "603f969cfe8bbdd01627037677526", 
"603f969cfe8bbdd01627038262733", "603f969cfe8bbdd01627039087330", 
"603f969cfe8bbdd01628162794749", "603f969cfe8bbdd01628163466481", 
"603f969cfe8bbdd01628163719815", "603f969cfe8bbdd01628158674517", 
"603f969cfe8bbdd01627637122289", "603f969cfe8bbdd01627638456949", 
"603f969cfe8bbdd01627638873663", "603f969cfe8bbdd01628164809630", 
"603f969cfe8bbdd01627911214100", "603f969cfe8bbdd01627910688328", 
"603f969cfe8bbdd01627911603237", "603f969cfe8bbdd01629434029000", 
"603f969cfe8bbdd01628256485431", "603f969cfe8bbdd01629434905241", 
"603f969cfe8bbdd01628852533054", "603f969cfe8bbdd01629435485937", 
"603f969cfe8bbdd01629120444754", "603f969cfe8bbdd01629122102484", 
"603f969cfe8bbdd01629120930436", "603f969cfe8bbdd01629462789885", 
"086113afa0b37fc41629722833545", "603f969cfe8bbdd01629455771970", 
"086113afa0b37fc41629181432848", "603f969cfe8bbdd01629456778209", 
"603f969cfe8bbdd01629457305431", "086113afa0b37fc41629182895251", 
"086113afa0b37fc41629184551829", "086113afa0b37fc41629186778675"
), date = c(1626159600, 1626161400, 1626162300, 1626163200, 1626164100, 
1626165000, 1626165900, 1626166800, 1626256800, 1626256800, 1626429600, 
1626429600, 1626429600, 1626699600, 1626678000, 1626678000, 1626688800, 
1627030800, 1627030800, 1627030800, 1627034400, 1627291800, 1627291800, 
1627291800, 1627304400, 1627637400, 1627637400, 1627637400, 1627894800, 
1627896600, 1628242200, 1628499600, 1628499600, 1629120420, 1628845200, 
1628847000, 1628505000, 1629093240, 1629108000, 1629108900, 1629109800, 
1629109800, 1629110700, 1629112500, 1629114300), datum = structure(c(1626166800, 
1626168600, 1626169500, 1626170400, 1626171300, 1626172200, 1626173100, 
1626174000, 1626264000, 1626264000, 1626436800, 1626436800, 1626436800, 
1626706800, 1626739200, 1626739200, 1626739200, 1627038000, 1627038000, 
1627038000, 1627041600, 1627299000, 1627299000, 1627299000, 1627311600, 
1627644600, 1627644600, 1627644600, 1627902000, 1627903800, 1628249400, 
1628506800, 1628506800, 1628812800, 1628852400, 1628854200, 1629072000, 
1629100440, 1629115200, 1629116100, 1629117000, 1629117000, 1629117900, 
1629119700, 1629121500), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), tijd = structure(c(1626166800, 1626168600, 1626169500, 
1626170400, 1626171300, 1626172200, 1626173100, 1626174000, 1626264000, 
1626264000, 1626436800, 1626436800, 1626436800, 1626706800, 1626685200, 
1626685200, 1626696000, 1627038000, 1627038000, 1627038000, 1627041600, 
1627299000, 1627299000, 1627299000, 1627311600, 1627644600, 1627644600, 
1627644600, 1627902000, 1627903800, 1628249400, 1628506800, 1628506800, 
1629127620, 1628852400, 1628854200, 1628512200, 1629100440, 1629115200, 
1629116100, 1629117000, 1629117000, 1629117900, 1629119700, 1629121500
), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), jaar = c(2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021
), projectnr = c(20210692, 20210692, 20210692, 20210692, 20210692, 
20210692, 20210692, 20210692, 20210692, 20210692, 20210692, 20210692, 
20210692, 20210692, 20210692, 20210692, 20210692, 20210692, 20210692, 
20210692, 20210692, 20210692, 20210692, 20210692, 20210692, 20210692, 
20210692, 20210692, 20210692, 20210692, 20210692, 20210692, 20210692, 
20210692, 20210692, 20210692, 20210692, 20210692, 20210692, 20210692, 
20210692, 20210692, 20210692, 20210692, 20210692), locatie = c("Berkenwoude", 
"Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", 
"Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", 
"Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", 
"Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", 
"Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", 
"Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", 
"Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", 
"Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", 
"Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude", "Berkenwoude"), 
    bemonstering = c("Monitoring", "Monitoring", "Monitoring", 
    "Monitoring", "Monitoring", "Monitoring", "Monitoring", "Monitoring", 
    "Afvissing", "Afvissing", "Afvissing", "Afvissing", "Afvissing", 
    "Afvissing", "Afvissing", "Afvissing", "Afvissing", "Afvissing", 
    "Afvissing", "Afvissing", "Afvissing", "Afvissing", "Afvissing", 
    "Afvissing", "Afvissing", "Afvissing", "Afvissing", "Afvissing", 
    "Afvissing", "Afvissing", "Afvissing", "Afvissing", "Afvissing", 
    "Afvissing", "Afvissing", "Afvissing", "Afvissing", "Afvissing", 
    "Afvissing", "Monitoring", "Afvissing", "Afvissing", "Monitoring", 
    "Monitoring", "Monitoring"), deelgebied = c("Referentiegebied", 
    "Referentiegebied", "Pilotgebied", "Pilotgebied", "Pilotgebied", 
    "Referentiegebied", "Referentiegebied", "Pilotgebied", "Fuiken Jan", 
    "Deelgebied 1", "Deelgebied 1", "Deelgebied 1", "Deelgebied 1", 
    "Fuiken Jan", "Deelgebied 1", "Deelgebied 1", "Deelgebied 1", 
    "Deelgebied 1", "Deelgebied 1", "Deelgebied 1", "Fuiken Jan", 
    "Deelgebied 1", "Deelgebied 1", "Deelgebied 1", "Fuiken Jan", 
    "Deelgebied 1", "Deelgebied 1", "Deelgebied 1", "Fuiken Jan", 
    "Deelgebied 2", "Deelgebied 2", "Deelgebied 2", "Fuiken Jan", 
    "Deelgebied 2", "Deelgebied 2", "Deelgebied 2", "Fuiken Jan", 
    "Fuiken Jan", "Deelgebied 2", "Pilotgebied", "Deelgebied 2", 
    "Deelgebied 2", "Pilotgebied", "Pilotgebied", "Pilotgebied"
    ), treknr = c("ref 4", "ref 3", "pil 2", "pil 3", "pil 4", 
    "ref 2", "ref 1", "pil 1", "fuiken Jan", "sloot 31/25", "sloot 24 met ring", 
    "sloot 24 zonder ring", "sloot 31/25", "fuiken Jan", "sloot 24 zonder ring", 
    "sloot 24 met ring", "sloot 31/25", "sloot 31/25", "sloot 24 met schoorsteen", 
    "sloot 24 zonder schoorsteen", "fuiken", "sloot 31/25", "sloot 24 zonder ring", 
    "sloot 24 met ring", "fuiken Jan", "sloot 24 zonder ring", 
    "sloot 31/25", "sloot 24 met ring", "fuiken jan de waard", 
    "sloot 18, 23, 22 en 21", "sloot 23 tot en met 13", "sloot 23 tot en met 13", 
    "Fuiken Jan", "sloot 13 met ring", "sloot 23 tot en met 14", 
    "sloot 13 zonder ring", "fuiken Jan de Waard", "fuiken 23-8-21", 
    "sloot 23 tot en met 14", "pil 4", "sloot 13 zonder schoorsteen", 
    "sloot 13 met schoorsteen", "pil 3", "pil 2", "pil 1"), gpsnr = c("gps03 (2dr150063)", 
    "gps03 (2dr150063)", "gps03 (2dr150063)", "gps03 (2dr150063)", 
    "gps03 (2dr150063)", "gps03 (2dr150063)", "gps03 (2dr150063)", 
    "gps03 (2dr150063)", "gps03 (2dr150063)", "gps03 (2dr150063)", 
    "gps03 (2dr150063)", "gps03 (2dr150063)", "gps03 (2dr150063)", 
    "gps03 (2dr150063)", "gps03 (2dr150063)", "gps03 (2dr150063)", 
    "gps03 (2dr150063)", "gps03 (2dr150063)", "gps03 (2dr150063)", 
    "gps03 (2dr150063)", "gps03 (2dr150063)", "gps03 (2dr150063)", 
    "gps03 (2dr150063)", "gps03 (2dr150063)", "gps03 (2dr150063)", 
    "gps03 (2dr150063)", "gps03 (2dr150063)", "gps03 (2dr150063)", 
    "gps03 (2dr150063)", "gps03 (2dr150063)", "gps03 (2dr150063)", 
    "gps03 (2dr150063)", "gps03 (2dr150063)", "gps03 (2dr150063)", 
    "gps03 (2dr150063)", "gps03 (2dr150063)", "gps03 (2dr150063)", 
    "YJ (53d212999)", "gps03 (2dr150063)", "YJ (53d212999)", 
    "gps03 (2dr150063)", "gps03 (2dr150063)", "YJ (53d212999)", 
    "YJ (53d212999)", "YJ (53d212999)"), weegschaalnr = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "ARCI-20 (150 kg)", NA, "HGS3000 (3kg)", 
    NA, NA, "HGS3000 (3kg)", "HGS3000 (3kg)", "HGS3000 (3kg)"
    ), meetplanknr = c("ME01", "ME01", "ME01", "ME01", "ME01", 
    "ME01", "ME01", "ME01", "ME01", "ME02", "ME01", "ME01", "ME01", 
    "ME01", "ME01", "ME01", "ME01", "ME01", "ME01", "ME01", "ME01", 
    "ME01", "ME01", "ME01", "ME01", "ME01", "ME01", "ME01", "ME02", 
    "ME01", "ME01", "ME02", "ME01", "ME01", "ME03", "ME01", "ME01", 
    "ME05", "ME01", "ME05", "ME01", "ME01", "ME05", "ME05", "ME05"
    ), uitvoerders = c("WJ JvG", "WJ JvG", "WJ JvG", "WJ JvG", 
    "WJ JvG", "WJ JvG", "WJ JvG", "WJ JvG", "Jan de Waard", "WJ JvG Nadine", 
    "WJ JvG Ad", "WJ JvG Ad", "WJ JvG Jan d Waard Ad", "Jan de Waard", 
    "WJ Ad", "WJ Ad", "wj ad", "Jouke Ad", "Jouke Ad", "Jouke Ad", 
    "Jan de Waard", "WJ Ad", "WJ Ad", "WJ Ad", "Jan de Waard", 
    "WJ Ad", "WJ Ad", "WJ Ad", "Jan de Waard", "WJ FB Ad", "JvG Ad", 
    "WJ WC", "Jan de Waard", "WJ", "WJ", "WJ", "WJ JWI", "sh jwi", 
    "WJ JWI", "hs jwi", "WJ JWI", "WJ JWI ad", "hs jwi", "hs jwi", 
    "hs jwi"), beginx = c(107912, 107867, 107775, 108033, 108265, 
    107455, 107423, 107443, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999
    ), beginy = c(438909, 438634, 438565, 438671, 438689, 438478, 
    438424, 438422, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999), 
    eindx = c(107915, 107914, 107719, 108085, 108265, 107503, 
    107416, 107441, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999), 
    eindy = c(438852, 438654, 438547, 438694, 438642, 438496, 
    438380, 438377, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 
    999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999, 999999), 
    dagnacht = c("Dag", "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", 
    "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", 
    "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", 
    "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", 
    "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", "Dag", 
    "Dag", "Dag"), vangtuig = c("Springkorf", "Springkorf", "Springkorf", 
    "Springkorf", "Springkorf", "Springkorf", "Springkorf", "Springkorf", 
    "Eenwieksfuik", "Springkorf", "Springkorf", "Springkorf", 
    "Springkorf", "Eenwieksfuik", "Springkorf", "Springkorf", 
    "Springkorf", "Springkorf", "Springkorf", "Springkorf", "Eenwieksfuik", 
    "Springkorf", "Springkorf", "Springkorf", "Eenwieksfuik", 
    "Springkorf", "Springkorf", "Springkorf", "Eenwieksfuik", 
    "Springkorf", "Springkorf", "Springkorf", "Eenwieksfuik", 
    "Springkorf", "Springkorf", "Springkorf", "Eenwieksfuik", 
    "Eenwieksfuik", "Springkorf", "Springkorf", "Springkorf", 
    "Springkorf", "Springkorf", "Springkorf", "Springkorf"), 
    vangtuig_specifikatie = c("Springkorf", "Springkorf", "Springkorf", 
    "Springkorf", "Springkorf", "Springkorf", "Springkorf", "Springkorf", 
    "Eenwieksfuik", "Springkorf", "Springkorf met ring", "Springkorf zonder ring", 
    "Springkorf", "Eenwieksfuik", "Springkorf zonder ring", "Springkorf met ring", 
    "Springkorf", "Springkorf", "Springkorf met ring", "Springkorf zonder ring", 
    "Eenwieksfuik", "Springkorf", "Springkorf zonder ring", "Springkorf met ring", 
    "Eenwieksfuik", "Springkorf zonder ring", "Springkorf", "Springkorf met ring", 
    "Eenwieksfuik", "Springkorf", "Springkorf", "Springkorf", 
    "Eenwieksfuik", "Springkorf met ring", "Springkorf", "Springkorf zonder ring", 
    "Eenwieksfuik", "Eenwieksfuik", "Springkorf", "Springkorf", 
    "Springkorf zonder ring", "Springkorf met ring", "Springkorf", 
    "Springkorf", "Springkorf"), treklengte_m = c(50, 50, 50, 
    50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 1, 1), waterdiepte_m = c("0.5", "0.7", "0.7", "0.6", 
    "0.4", "0.6", "0.6", "0.6", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", 
    "0", "1", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1"), doorzicht_m = c(0.3, 
    0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), substraat = c("zand", "zand", 
    "zand", "zand", "zand", "zand", "zand", "zand", "zand", "zand", 
    "zand", "zand", "zand", "zand", "zand", "zand", "zand", "zand", 
    "zand", "zand", "zand", "zand", "zand", "zand", "zand", "zand", 
    "zand", "zand", "zand", "zand", "zand", "zand", "zand", "zand", 
    "zand", "zand", "zand", "zand", "zand", "zand", "zand", "zand", 
    "zand", "zand", "zand"), diktesliblaag_m = c(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 
    0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), beschoeiing = c("Nee", "Nee", "Nee", 
    "Nee", "Nee", "Nee", "Nee", "Nee", "Nee", "Nee", "Nee", "Nee", 
    "Nee", "Nee", "Nee", "Nee", "Nee", "Nee", "Nee", "Nee", "Nee", 
    "Nee", "Nee", "Nee", "Nee", "Nee", "Nee", "Nee", "Nee", "Nee", 
    "Nee", "Nee", "Nee", "Nee", "Nee", "Nee", "Nee", "Nee", "Nee", 
    "Nee", "Nee", "Nee", "Nee", "Nee", "Nee"), typebeschoeiing = c("NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL"), percentagebeschoeiing = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), oeverlandgebruik = c("weilanden", "weilanden", 
    "Weilanden", "weilanden", "weilanden", "weilanden", "weilanden", 
    "weilanden", "weilanden", "weilanden", "weilanden", "weilanden", 
    "weilanden", "weilanden", "weilanden", "weilanden", "weilanden", 
    "weilanden", "weilanden", "weilanden", "weilanden", "weilanden", 
    "weilanden", "weilanden", "weilanden", "weilanden", "weilanden", 
    "weilanden", "weilanden", "weilanden", "weilanden", "NULL", 
    "weilanden", "natuur", "weilanden", "weilanden", "weilanden", 
    "NULL", "weilanden", "NULL", "weilanden", "weilanden", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL"), onderwatertalud = c("NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "Matig flauw (30-45 graden)", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "Matig flauw (30-45 graden)", "Matig flauw (30-45 graden)", 
    "Matig flauw (30-45 graden)"), submers = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), submerssoorten = c("NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL"), drijfblad = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), drijfbladsoorten = c("NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL"), kroos = c(1, 30, 0, 0, 0, 
    15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), kroossoorten = c("Klein kroos", "Klein kroos", "Klein kroos", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "Klein kroos", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL"), flab = c(0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), draadwier = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), emers = c(100, 100, 100, 75, 10, 65, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    emerssoorten = c("Kleine egelskop, Liesgras", "Kleine egelskop, Liesgras", 
    "Kleine egelskop, Rietgras", "Liesgras, Rietgras", "Kleine egelskop, Liesgras", 
    "Kleine egelskop, Liesgras", "Pitrus", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL"), emersbreedte = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 
    0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), fotonummers = c("NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", NA, "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL"), overigeopmerkingen = c("NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "bijvangst: 4 RV, 6 BV, 2 KB, 4 BA, 12 ZE, 13 GI", 
    "bijvangst: 8 kikkers, 3 bruine ratten, 8 tuimelaar kevers", 
    "korven met ontsnappings ring", "korven zonder ontsnappings ring. ook 1 rat gevangen", 
    "bijvangst: aantal RV,GI,SK, 3 bruine ratten, 2 eenden kuikens", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "kreeften niet apart verwerkt", 
    "kreeften niet apart verwerkt", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", 
    "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL"), lastUpdate = structure(c(1628503221, 
    1628503221, 1628503221, 1628503221, 1628503221, 1628503221, 
    1628503221, 1628503221, 1628503173, 1626878646, 1626880292, 
    1626879955, 1626879419, 1628503173, 1628503173, 1628503173, 
    1628503173, 1628503173, 1628503173, 1628503173, 1628503173, 
    1627645416, 1627646063, 1627646497, 1628503173, 1628503173, 
    1628503173, 1628503173, 1629442074, 1628503173, 1629442639, 
    1628860881, 1629442935, 1629128897, 1629129893, 1629128903, 
    1629470475, 1629746055, 1629463968, 1629230264, 1629464475, 
    1629464725, 1629225487, 1629230450, 1629225312), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), appversion = c("1.0.3", "1.0.3", "1.0.3", "1.0.3", 
    "1.0.3", "1.0.3", "1.0.3", "1.0.3", "1.0.3", "1.0.3", "1.0.3", 
    "1.0.3", "1.0.3", "1.0.3", "1.0.3", "1.0.3", "1.0.3", "1.0.3", 
    "1.0.3", "1.0.3", "1.0.3", "1.0.3", "1.0.3", "1.0.3", "1.0.3", 
    "1.0.3", "1.0.3", "1.0.3", "1.0.3", "1.0.3", "1.0.3", "1.0.3", 
    "1.0.3", "1.0.3", "1.0.3", "1.0.3", "1.0.3", "1.0.4", "1.0.3", 
    "1.0.4", "1.0.3", "1.0.3", "1.0.4", "1.0.4", "1.0.4"), deelgebied_1 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "fuiken", NA, NA, NA, NA, "fuiken", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "fuiken", NA, NA, NA, "fuiken", NA, 
    NA, NA, "fuiken", NA, NA, NA, "fuiken", NA, NA, NA, "fuiken", 
    "fuiken", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), aantal_vangtuigeenheden = c(12, 
    12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 90, 332, 5, 39, 332, 165, 39, 
    5, 356, 356, 5, 39, 160, 356, 39, 5, 62, 39, 356, 5, 136, 
    180, 400, 400, 138, 5, 381, 39, 30, 150, 381, 12, 39, 5, 
    12, 12, 12), vangtuig_opgehaald = c(1626250500, 1626248700, 
    1626246900, 1626244200, 1626242400, 1626255000, 1626257700, 
    1626256800, 1626688800, 1627034400, 1626764400, 1626764400, 
    1626778800, 1627045200, 1627023600, 1627023660, 1627034400, 
    1627290000, 1627290000, 1627290000, 1627293600, 1627635600, 
    1627635600, 1627635600, 1627909200, 1627902000, 1627903800, 
    1627903800, 1628499600, 1628242200, 1628501400, 1628845200, 
    1629104400, 1629106140, 1629104400, 1629106200, 1629460800, 
    1629698040, 1629453600, 1629181800, 1629455400, 1629455400, 
    1629182400, 1629183900, 1629185700), `datum opgehaald` = structure(c(1626257700, 
    1626255900, 1626254100, 1626251400, 1626249600, 1626262200, 
    1626264900, 1626264000, 1626696000, 1626393600, 1626771600, 
    1626771600, 1626786000, 1627052400, 1627030800, 1627030860, 
    1627041600, 1627297200, 1627297200, 1627297200, 1627300800, 
    1627642800, 1627642800, 1627642800, 1627916400, 1627909200, 
    1627911000, 1627911000, 1628506800, 1628249400, 1628508600, 
    1628852400, 1629111600, 1629072000, 1629111600, 1629113400, 
    1629468000, 1629705240, 1629460800, 1629189000, 1629462600, 
    1629462600, 1629189600, 1629191100, 1629192900), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), `aantal nachten` = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    5, 1.49999999999272, 3.875, 3.875, 4.04166666665697, 4, 3.37500000000728, 
    3.37569444444671, 3.50000000000728, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3.97916666667152, 
    3.97916666667152, 3.97916666667152, 7, 3.0625, 3.08333333334303, 
    3.08333333334303, 7, 4, 3, 4, 7, 3, 3, 3, 4.58333333333576, 
    7, 4, 1, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1), totaalgewicht_vangst = c("1.7649999999999999", 
    "0.21", "1.788", "1.63", "2.0449999999999999", "1.67", "0.83499999999999996", 
    "1.42", "70", "53.25", "1.75", "12.3", "59.55", "54", "6.4", 
    "0.6", "35.450000000000003", "53.3", "0", "0", "63", "39.299999999999997", 
    "5.25", "0.65", "56", "4.0999999999999996", "26.05", "0.3", 
    "104.5", "41.2", "79.3", "60.95", "46", "0.7", "43.5", "2.95", 
    "10.3", "56.4", "38.4", "1", "3.65", "0.5", "0.08", "0.57999999999999996", 
    "1"), vangstverwerking = c("Totaal", "Totaal", "Totaal", 
    "Totaal", "Totaal", "Totaal", "Totaal", "Totaal", "Totaal", 
    "Totaal", "Totaal", "Totaal", "Totaal", "Totaal", "Totaal", 
    "Totaal", "Totaal", "Totaal", "Totaal", "Totaal", "Totaal", 
    "Totaal", "Totaal", "Totaal", "Totaal", "Totaal", "Totaal", 
    "Totaal", "Totaal", "Totaal", "Totaal", "Totaal", "Totaal", 
    "Totaal", "Totaal", "Totaal", "Totaal", "Totaal", "Totaal", 
    "Totaal", "Totaal", "Totaal", "Totaal", "Totaal", "Totaal"
    ), arbeidstijd = c(30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 240, 7, 
    60, 60, 7, 240, 60, 60, 240, 240, 60, 60, 240, 240, 60, 60, 
    240, 30, 240, 30, 240, 240, 240, 240, 240, 30, 240, 30, 60, 
    300, 240, 20, 60, 30, 15, 20, 20), vangsteenheden_overzicht = c("0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
    "NULL", "0", "NULL", "0", "0", "NULL", "NULL", "NULL"), `CPUE [kg]` = c(0.147083333333333, 
    0.0175, 0.149, 0.135833333333333, 0.170416666666667, 0.139166666666667, 
    0.0695833333333333, 0.118333333333333, 0.155555555555556, 
    0.106927710843892, 0.0903225806451613, 0.0813895781637717, 
    0.0443795801764821, 0.0818181818181818, 0.0486229819562105, 
    0.0355482411026299, 0.0284510433386246, 0.0499063670411985, 
    0, 0, 0.13125, 0.0277428084004603, 0.0338300443012073, 0.032670157068023, 
    0.129032258064516, 0.03432757718472, 0.0237321591253429, 
    0.0194594594593982, 0.109768907563025, 0.0572222222222222, 
    0.0660833333333333, 0.03809375, 0.0476190476190476, 0.0466666666666667, 
    0.0380577427821522, 0.0252136752136752, 0.0749090909090513, 
    0.0537142857142857, 0.0251968503937008, 0.0833333333333333, 
    0.0233974358974359, 0.025, 0.00666666666666667, 0.0483333333333333, 
    0.0833333333333333)), row.names = c(NA, -45L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you expect 48 everywhere, just checking your sample data and picking one group out. We see pretty fast that are just 3 records for that grouping, so why you expect another sum for aantal_vangtuigeenheden than 36?

```
cpue_monitoring  %>% filter(locatie == "Berkenwoude" & deelgebied == "Pilotgebied" & `datum opgehaald` == as.Date("2021-08-17"))

# A tibble: 3 x 7
  jaar  locatie     bemonstering deelgebied  aantal_vangtuigeenheden `datum opgehaald` totaalgewicht_vangst
  <chr> <chr>       <chr>        <chr>                         <dbl> <date>                           <dbl>
1 2021  Berkenwoude Monitoring   Pilotgebied                      12 2021-08-17                        1   
2 2021  Berkenwoude Monitoring   Pilotgebied                      12 2021-08-17                        0.08
3 2021  Berkenwoude Monitoring   Pilotgebied                      12 2021-08-17                        0.58
```

So if your files originally had more rows there, your problem lies one step earlier, for example while reading your data into R.

Comment: I think you are right! Something doesn't go correctly when I convert some column types: it seems NA are introduced by this code: Data_traject$totaalgewicht_vangst   <- as.numeric(Data_traject$totaalgewicht_vangst). But it is just a simple transformation

Comment: I added my original dataset, if you could try to duplicate this, then you should find 4 rows in the original dataset and 3 rows with date 2021-08-17 in the cpue_monitoring dataset

Comment: Which one is the one you need, note that session id 603f969cfe8bbdd01629120444754 has a datum of 2021-08-13 00:00:00 and a tijd of 2021-08-16 15:27:00 while in most rows we see similar timestamps in both columns. It seems that you derive the tijd opgehaald based on datum but perhaps those are the ones missing as they fall into another date you group on.

Comment: That could also be influencing the outcome, but I think the main problem was in the command `unique`, which I used to extract columns. However, it removed the dupiclates ofcourse... which I thought I did not have any. Problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

As @Merijn van Tilborg also mentions, the 36 seems to be calculated in a right way. You can use the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
cpue_monitoring <- cpue_monitoring %>%
  mutate(Datum = format(date(cpue_monitoring$`datum opgehaald`), "%Y-%m-%d")) %>%
  group_by(locatie, deelgebied, Datum) %>% 
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum))
```

Output:

```
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'locatie', 'deelgebied'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 44 × 5
# Groups:   locatie, deelgebied [5]
   locatie     deelgebied       Datum      aantal_vangtuigeenheden totaalgewicht_vangst
   <chr>       <chr>            <chr>                        <dbl>                <dbl>
 1 Berkenwoude Pilotgebied      2021-07-14                      48                6.88 
 2 Berkenwoude Pilotgebied      2021-08-17                      36                1.66 
 3 Berkenwoude Pilotgebied      2021-09-14                      48                2.47 
 4 Berkenwoude Pilotgebied      2021-10-19                      48                5.05 
 5 Berkenwoude Pilotgebied      2021-11-17                      36                0.68 
 6 Berkenwoude Pilotgebied      2021-12-17                      48                1.83 
 7 Berkenwoude Pilotgebied      2022-01-18                      48                0.567
 8 Berkenwoude Pilotgebied      2022-02-18                      48                4.07 
 9 Berkenwoude Pilotgebied      2022-03-17                      48                2.33 
10 Berkenwoude Referentiegebied 2021-07-14                      48                4.48
```